# How to read resources/config.properties between parent and child jar in Maven

Tags: scala, maven

There are two project(A-primary, A-secondary).

The folder strucute will like this

========================

A-primary

-/resources

--config.properties

=========================

A-secondary

-/resources

--config.properties

=======================

**** Issue ****
The A-secondary project require the jar file of A-primary after A-primary execute maven install command on the local. And then A-secondary need to get the realted value from the A-primary which takes from config.properties.

But A-secondary always get A-secondary's config.properties rather than A-primary config.properties.

**** Question ****
How do I put the properties correctly on A-primary so that A-secondary can get the value from A-primary config.properties successfully? Meanwhile, B-secondary can get its config.properties.

If I obey the Maven design principle for getting config value, please help to provide some related source for good architecture design.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

## [Resolved] Rename these properties as different name can resolve this issue.

A-primary

-/resources

--A_primary_config.properties

=========================

A-secondary

-/resources

--A_secondary_config.properties

=======================

But I recommend the developer to use "typesafe library" to resolve the configuration, it is better than read properties files.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).